Gpu fans ramping up when powering off
I have Ubuntu 24.04 lts and when I power off the pc or restart it, the GPU fans are ramping up to 100% and I also hear some coilwhine or some beeping. It feels like it is going full power 2-3 seconds before shutting down.
I have corectrl installed to control my gpu fans. Does it have any impact on this problem?
Have anyone encountered this problem or is it normal?
I couldn't find any related topics so I just don't know where to start troubleshooting.
On windows it does not happen.
My gpu is RX 580 8gb and motherboard is DQ67SW.
Thanks!

it may be the case of the motherboard firmware taking control of the fans ... do the fans run at 100% when in setup (bios)?

no, it does not happen. only when powering off/restarting from ubuntu.

That's the way the fan controller should work: "We're losing power, might as well exhaust as much heat as we can, while we can".
